# Share the blank space of columns with other columns

Tags: tables, columns

[image: Blank space in column 1 should be shared with other columns]

As you can see in the image, I want the blank space of column 1 to be shared with other columns so the table looks more neat and best for readers.

`\setcolsep` does not solve this issue.

**UPDATE: Fixed the code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |}
\hline
ویژگی & TCP & UDP\\\hline
نوع ارتباط & بر اساس اتصال & بدون برقراری اتصال (ممکن است هر مقدار اطلاعات فرستاده شود و آن پایان ارتباط باشد)\\
مزیت & ارتباط قابل اطمینان & سرعت بالا\\
استفاده پروتکل های دیگر & \lr{HTTP}\footnote{\lr{Hypertext Transfer Protocol}}, \lr{HTTPS}\footnote{\lr{Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure}}, \lr{FTP}\footnote{\lr{File Transfer Protocol}}, \lr{Telnet} & \lr{DNS}\footnote{\lr{Domain Name System}}, \lr{DHCP}\footnote{\lr{Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol}}, \lr{VOIP}\footnote{\lr{Voice over Internet Protocol}}\\
نظم ارسال & طبق نظم مشخص شده & بدون نظم\\
سایز هدر & \lr{20 Bytes} & \lr{8 Bytes}\\
خطایابی & بله & بله\\
بازیابی & بله (پس از خطایابی، اطلاعاتی که اشتباه انتقال یافته اند دوباره منتقل می شوند) & خیر\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried making the third column `r` instead of `X`?

Comment: @TeXnician I don't want to because I'm using `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` Added that to code

Comment: Please make your document compilable to help us help you. As it is one cannot copy, paste and compile.

Comment: @TeXnician I think I added all packages needed, What's not compiling? You need to install the XePersian Package from TeX Live Manager first.

Comment: Copy your above code and try to run it with `xelatex` and you'll see what a compilable document means.

Comment: @Shayan: You could also change the third column from `X` to `m{n}` with `n` being a width of your choice.

Comment: you could use `tabulary` rather than `tabularx` to allow the column widths to be determined automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
   | >{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X 
   | >{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X 
   | >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X |}
 [...]
```

the `\hsize` should be added 3X

Comment: Nope still getting that blank space http://prntscr.com/htp4bv prolly because tables are so complicated in LaTeX, maybe I should try Longtable?

Comment: What does `>` in `>{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X` do though?

Comment: your answer worked, problem was, for different paper sizes the result is going to be different (That's what I hate) so I was looking for a way for LaTeX to automatically use the blank space for other columns, well tbh that's too much to ask, even MS Word doesn't do that, so it's only possible to set it manually thanks `{| >{\hsize=0.6\hsize}X | >{\hsize=1\hsize}X | X |}` worked

Comment: in fact the above sizes were generating the table as if there's a new column, so for other readers `{| >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X | >{\hsize=1.15\hsize}X | >{\hsize=1.15\hsize}X |}` worked the best, the numbers of `\hsize` should add up to 3 (since there are three columns)